# How to send on my Web Api ASP.Net Core 6.0 file with two params from WPF app C# using RestSharp STATUS CODE ERROR 44

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, desktop, restsharp

I have method in my API which receives a file, int and string params. Also I have a desktop WPF app (written in C#) where user after choosing some options click on button and app create request to API using RestSharp.

In this request I need to transfer a `.zip` file, int and string params. But I get an exception status code 44. I test my method in Postman and it works. Please help.

This is what my API method receives:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("AddFile")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        
        int comicsId = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["comicsId"]);
        string issueName = Request.Form["issueName"].ToString();
```

This is the desktop WPF app code:

```
private void BtnCreateAdd_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cbComicsName.SelectedItem == null || tbPath.Text.Trim().Length == 0 || tbIssueName.Text.Trim().Length==0)
    {
        
    }
    else
    {
        var fileParameter = FileParameter.FromFile(tbPath.Text);
        ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = (ComboBoxItem)cbComicsName.SelectedItem;
            var response = apiClient.Post(new RestRequest("download/addfile")
                .AddParameter("comicsId",Convert.ToInt32(comboBoxItem.Tag))
                .AddParameter("issueName",tbIssueName.Text)
                .AddFile("file",fileParameter.GetFile,fileParameter.FileName,fileParameter.ContentType));
            MessageBox.Show(response.Content);


    }
}
```

This is error

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Request failed with status code 44
```

This is the way I use Postman to check method with it successful code

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as image, we can't use it to help you. Provide code.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... fixed

Comment: I still see code in images

Comment: Now it's okay? Below two images, others are screens errors and postman

Comment: No, is not. Is not very clear the error. Do not use images if they are code or messages. Please read the guide. Also you have still images with code.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. What about my final masterpiece of asking question?